# How to cut/paste a line in WebStorm, keeping indentation?

Tags: indentation, copy-paste, webstorm

I started using Webstorm, and I can't figure out to how cut/paste a line keeping the **exact same** indentation.

In Jade file:

```
.something
  ul
    li
      label -->Cut this line<--
    li
      label some text
```

I put the cursor at the beginning of the above-specified line. Then, `Edit -> Cut` and `Edit -> Paste`. I end up with:

```
.something
  ul
    li
label -->Cut this line<--
  li
      label some text
```

I want the indentation to be exactly the same as before. How do I achieve this?

I tried all the options in `Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Reformat on paste` and none of them made any difference.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can change the settings so that it doesn't alter the formatting when you paste.

**File** > **Settings** > **Editor** > **General** > **Smart Keys** .. then look for the '**Reformat on paste:**' and select None from the drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

When editing Jade, on pasting a code block the position of the 'top' element in pasted fragment is equal to current cursor position, other elements are indented to the same level relative to top element as in original fragment. So you have to make sure to put cursor not at the beginning of line, but at the desired position... For example, hit Enter after `<li>` and then paste

Comment: This explains what's happening, but doesn't answer the question. I have the same problem, used to paste keeping all the spaces intact. Is there a way to tell to webstorm not to do that much work for me and just trust my copy paste?

Comment: Thanks for this answer - this was really bugging me in both IntelliJ and Webstorm for jade and stylus. Another work around is to highlight the lines and move them - on Mac, after highlighting, this is OPTION+SHIFT and up and down arrows.

Answer (score 0):

use Ctrl+Shift+Alt+V for simple paste

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/cutting-copying-and-pasting.html?origin=old_help